# Using additional entropy from (semi-)untrusted sources

Tags: security, cryptography, entropy

Lets say I have a program that generates secret keys. It's important that these secrets keys are cryptographically strong.

Now, this program would be used on a lot of different computers, and I suspect that at least on some of them the random number generator will be week, insufficiently seeded (e.g. a VM), or just straight broken.

So I'm considering additional hardening, by fetching some entropy from 3rd party sources, hashing that and "XORing it" with my locally generated entropy.

The question is: Is this a good idea?

The way I see it is:

- If the local random number generator is working right, the 3rd party entropy providers can't weaken the final entropy in any way, even if they send "malicious" entropy. Also, any attacker can't gain anything by somehow intercepting in transit the entropy provided.
- If the local random number generator was indeed bad, any honest 3rd party entropy provider that sent properly random entropy will save the final entropy from being week. And as long as an attacker wasn't able to intercept it, the user is saved from using a weak secret key.

Are these correct conclusions?

Other than potential privacy downsides, is there anything else to worry about?

Comment: Have a look at the [Fortuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)) CSPRNG which accumulates entropy from multiple sources, some more reliable than others.

Comment: Thanks. Fortuna looks like a structured approach with more sources using the same underlying idea.